# Excel Error “You’ve entered too many arguments”

Tags: microsoft-excel

The formula I entered was

```
=IF(I13=1,K19,IF(AND(I13=2,I18>0),J22,J23,IF(AND(I13=3,I18>0),J29,J23)))
```

Comment: And...? What have you tried? The error is pretty clear and well documented too.

Answer (score 2):

The error is that the inner IF has four arguments instead of three:

```
=IF(I13=1,K19,IF(AND(I13=2,I18>0),J22,J23,IF(AND(I13=3,I18>0),J29,J23)))
                 1                2   3   4
```

When you get the error, Excel 365 outlines in color the bad function
(although it could be done somewhat better):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the formula to:

```
=IF(I13=1,K19,IF(AND(I13=2,I18>0),J22,IF(AND(I13=3,I18>0),J29,J23)))
```